# display none if null using data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which list items which display the the content on the other list.

MENU

```
<ul id="gallery-list" style="display: none;">
        <li class="close"></li>
        <li data-id="9425"><strong>item 1</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9426"><strong>item 2</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9488"><strong>item 3</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9489"><strong>item 4</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9495"><strong>item 5</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9427"><strong>item 6</strong></li>
</ul>
```

CONTENT:

```
<ul id="gallery-container">
        <li data-id="9425">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 1</h3>
            <div class="content">Content here</div>
        </li>
        <li data-id="9426">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 2</h3>
        </li>
        <li data-id="9488">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 3</h3>
        </li>
        <li data-id="9489">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 4</h3>
        </li>
        <li data-id="9495">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 5</h3>
            <div class="content">Content here</div>
        </li>
        <li data-id="9427">
            <h3 style="display: none;">Item 6</h3>
            <div class="content">Content here</div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

In the content some have `.content` in the `li`. How can I use the data-id in that to hide the item in the menu section? Basically items in the menu should only be display if it has a `.content`

OUTPUT of the MENU should be like this.

```
<ul id="gallery-list" style="display: none;">
        <li class="close"></li>
        <li data-id="9425"><strong>item 1</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9495"><strong>item 5</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9427"><strong>item 6</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Or this should be okay too.

```
<ul id="gallery-list" style="display: none;">
        <li class="close"></li>
        <li data-id="9425"><strong>item 1</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9425" style="display:none;"><strong>item 2</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9425" style="display:none;"><strong>item 3</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9425" style="display:none;"><strong>item 4</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9495"><strong>item 5</strong></li>
        <li data-id="9427"><strong>item 6</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Take not that Item in the content are always `display:none;` onload trigger.

Also using this script:

```
    $("#gallery-list li").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
            $("#gallery-container").find('li').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.content').toggle($(this).data('id') === id);
            $(this).find('h3').toggle($(this).data('id') === id);
        });
    });
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#gallery-container li .content").css("display", "none");
        $("#gallery-container li h3").css("display","none");
        $("#gallery-container li p").css("display","none");
    }
    $('.gallery-menu h3, #gallery-list li').click(function(){
        $("#gallery-list, .gallery-menu h3").toggle();
    });
```

This controls the contents of the list also activate the menu.

Comment: Nitpicking: `window.onload = function () {...}` ought to be `$( window ).load( function() { ... } )`, or you might override other onload events happening (jQuery allows multiple event handlers this way). Also if you're using `toggle()` you should use `hide()` and `show()` for consistency rather than `css('display','...')`

Comment: thank you for noticing that @XerenNarcy

Answer (score 2):

My frist idea:
Loop the content list items and when no `.content` is available inside, `remove` the related menu item.

```
$(function() {
    $("#gallery-container li[data-id]").each(function() {
        if( $(".content", this).length == 0 ) {
            $("#gallery-list li[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

As @XerenNarcy noticed in the comments, you can even use a `not()` and `has()` combined selector:

```
$(function() {
    $("#gallery-container li[data-id]:not(:has(.content))").each(function() {
        $("#gallery-list li[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").remove();
    });
});
```

Instead of `remove()` you yould even use `hide()`.

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/t264bdyh/2/)**

Comment: You could make this a bit simpler, using the `:has` selector, eg: `#gallery-container li[data-id]:has(.content)`

Comment: You're right, but it should be `:not(:has(.content))` then, @XerenNarcy

Comment: No wait... not `:not(:has())`?

Comment: `remove` removes elements from DOM, you might want `.hide()`

Comment: Haha, @MIke, now you remove success because I criticized your other question? ;) Very adult.