# Execute an if condition if a button is not inside a <tr> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute my `if` condition only when a `button` is not inside the `tr`. Here is my code:

```
if (!$("tr").hasClass('hidebutton')) {
    var OriginalContent = $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").text();
    $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html("<button class=hidebutton>-</button> " + OriginalContent + " ");
}
```

But it is not working. The `if` condition is executing all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display none if null using data-id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651489/display-none-if-null-using-data-id)

Comment: sorry i don't get it..can you please explain

Comment: You want to execute something whenever a `button` is not in the `tr`, right? So it is like in the posted question. You could go with something like `tr:not(:has(button))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I get a little of what you want.

It seems like  you were to create a button if no button found inside "tr" right? If I'm correct, you may play the snippet below.

```
if(!$("tr button").hasClass("hidebutton")){
 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html('<button class="hidebutton">-</button> ' + OriginalContent);
}
```

by the way it seems like you missed something on this line

```
html("<button class=hidebutton>-</button> " + OriginalContent + " ");
```

You need to enclose hidebutton like this 'hidebutton' see below;

```
.html("<button class='hidebutton'>-</button> " + OriginalContent + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a loop:

```
$("tr").each(function( index, value ) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hidebutton')){
        console.log($(this,"td:first-child").text());
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btqsmdxv/)